# Получить записи из MYSQL только за вчерашний день

Tags: unixtimestamp, mysql

Нужно получить записи за вчерашний день. Данный способ получает как-то неправильно, выводятся записи за сегодня и вчера.. В чём проблема?

```
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(INTERVAL - 1 day + CURRENT_DATE()) < ttime
```

Comment: вы вроде спрашиваете у мускула "дай мне рез-ты, время у которых больше, чем начало вчера.    
то есть сегодня и вчера...    
а надо еще спросить"...но при этом больше, чем начало сегодня "

Comment: @metalurgus, если не составит труда, то напишите, пожалуйста запрос..

Comment: к сожалению, составит((не знаю функций мускула, по этому свое предположение оформил, как комментарий, а не ответ... Сформировал его просто судя по тому, что проверка производится только в одну сторону(<), а во вторую - не производится. То есть вы проверяете на "больше, чем начало вчера", но забываете проверить на "меньше, чем начало сегодня".   
Но все же попробую...  Что-то в роде этого    

    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(INTERVAL - 1 day + CURRENT_DATE()) < ttime AND    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) > ttime

Comment: еще можно из даты записи "выдрать" число и месяц, и сравнить их с выдранными значениями из вчерашней даты...

Comment: @metalurgus, сработало! Превратите свой комментарий в ответ!

Comment: магия...)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка производится только в одну сторону(<), а во вторую - не производится. То есть вы проверяете на "больше, чем начало вчера", но забываете проверить на "меньше, чем начало сегодня". 
Примерно так это должно выглядеть:

```
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(INTERVAL - 1 day + CURRENT_DATE()) < ttime AND    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) > ttime
```

Comment: @metalurgus, готово :) Спасибо Вам огромное!